# I am getting this error when I check my Google chrome browser console: "GET http://localhost:3000/posts 404 (Not Found)"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am learning to connect my React app to my nodejs backend by following a video tutorial from YouTube. I did everything so far based on the tutorial but I am getting error at this stage and I can't seem to figure it out. Google couldnt help me too.
I am trying to fetch data from the data base on the homepage.
Here is the error messages on Google chrome browser:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/posts 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
at createError (createError.js:16)
at settle (settle.js:17)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)
```

**This is the code from the React file named home.jsx:**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Header from '../../components/header/header';
import Posts from '../../components/posts/posts';
import Sidebar from '../../components/sidebar/sidebar';
import './home.css';
import axios from "axios";

export default function Home() {
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() =>{
    const fetchPosts = async () =>{
        const res = await axios.get("/posts")
     console.log(res)
    }
    fetchPosts()
}, [])
return (
   <>
        <Header/>
        <div className='home'>
            <Posts/>
            <Sidebar/>
        </div>
    </>
 )
 }
```

This is the node.js route path:

```
const postRoute = require("./routes/posts");
app.use("/api/posts", postRoute);
```

This is the package.json api path:

```
   ]
   }, "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/api"
   }
```

I appreciate any help rendered. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found out that I needed to restart my React app when I made changes to the package.json file. This worked immediately and I could fetch the data..

Answer (score 0):

It's possible it could be related to your express implementation.

Here are some examples of an express app setup where I was able to successfully receive the data when using

```
fetch("/posts")
```

##### posts.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send({
    test: "1"
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

##### server.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const postRoute = require("./routes/posts");

app.use("/api/posts", postRoute);

app.listen(5000);
```

Note: If you make changes to your proxy in `package.json` you must restart your react app.